# Variant of K-fold CV where size(test_set) > N/K

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a binary classification problem that has a huge imbalance in the label 0 and 1 (minority). Because the testing set has too few rows with label 1, I make the train-test at least 70-30 or 60-40, so there are still significant observations. As I am not measuring so much on Accuracy ( due to class imbalance), but more on Precision-Recall, this is especially more important as a few difference in True Positives is significant.

Is there a variant of KFold (or cross validation method) in Python / sklearn where I choose K = 5, and set the split to 60-40? Just like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted on this question. Whoever you are, could you please bother explaining at least.

Comment: Not sure who downgraded, i found it a legit query. 
I have tried to answer below for you

Comment: Let me know if my response was any helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need Stratified sampling to handle the imbalance.
Here is the URL where sklearn does it for you : combining Kfold and Stratified sampling/split

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html